# Processing spectral data in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst, matlab-deployment

I am trying to calculate Chlorite Spectral Maturity (CSM) and Illite Spectral Maturity (ISM) scalars using the below formula. So far I have been able to read my data using the below matlab script but I am not sure how to implement my formula. Please, I need help. Thank you.

FORMULA:

CSM Scalar
 = (1 − ((2310:2370)) ) + 1.7 ∗ (1 − ((2240:2270)))/(((1810:2140)) − ((1900:2020)))

ISM Scalar
 = ((2136:2296) − ((2140:2270)))/(((1810:2140)) − ((1900:2020)))

MATHLAB SCRIPT BELOW:

```
fname='filename_'; 
data=zeros(13048,498);

for i=1:498
      str=strcat(fname,sprintf('%04d',i),'.asd');
      fid=fopen(str,'r');

      data(:,i)=fread(fid,'float32');

      fclose(fid);
end
x=1:13048;y=1:13048;
plot3(x,y,data(:,100));grid on;

plot(data(:,1));`
```

Comment: This is unreadable

Comment: Thanks Dave2e for editing the script.

Comment: Are minv, maxv and hr some array operations that are specified in some paper?

Comment: Those actually refer to the spectral peak or depth